# Docker Angular Development Environment

Tags: angular, docker

I am trying to set up an Angular docker environment.

I would like the container to rebuild the angular app when I change a file similar to how if you run it locally on your machine.

Below is the Dockerfile that does build and serve the angular app.

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:17.0.1-bullseye-slim as builder
EXPOSE 4200

WORKDIR /app

RUN npm install -g @angular/cli@13

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

COPY . .
CMD ["ng", "serve", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--disable-host-check"]
```

and a docker-compose file that looks like:

```
services:
  ui:
    container_name: ui
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'
    volumes:
      - /.:/app
```

How can I make the container rebuild the angular app, serve the newly built app, and refresh the browser?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you need any of the setup or artifacts shown here; just install Node and you'll have an actual local development setup.  What are you hoping to gain from using Docker here?

Comment: I want to build the image and use it in a dev environment. we have about 20 services that we would like to add to make it easier to develop. They are in multiple repositories and some teams have access to some others have to pulll the image.

Comment: @DavidMaze, What are you saying i do not need here?

Comment: I agree with @DavidMaze. It doesn't seem like you will get any benefit from serving the app inside a container. Though, you should not use `ng serve` in such a place that is intended for prod use. You can spin up other services as usual with Docker, and then use env variables to connect them to the Angular app that is being run on the local machine.

Comment: I would not use ```ng serve```, i would use ```ENTRYPOINT [ "npm" ]

CMD ["start"]```

Comment: For a development environment?  Installing Node is probably 2-3 characters shorter than installing Docker, and then you do not need either of these files, a `volumes:` mount to disable Docker's core filesystem isolation feature, and you won't need to "sync filesystems" or figure out why it's not working.